# Add MouseListener with reference to other class

Tags: java, static, awt

I want to add MouseListener to a class which extends JPanel. The Listener references to another class where the JPanel itself is created and added to contentPane. By pressing the mouse on JPanel, it should be removed. It is working well but I cannot call repaint() because my removing methode is static. How I can solve this?

This is the extended class:

```
public class PanelDraggable extends JPanel {

public PanelDraggable () {

    .
    .
    .

    MouseInputAdapter closeMouseAdapter = new CloseMouseHandler();
    addMouseListener(closeMouseAdapter);

}


private class CloseMouseHandler extends MouseInputAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            TblManagement.RemoveTable();
        }
}
```

}

And in this class I want to create the panel and remove it:

```
public void AddTables() {

    String dbShortName = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String dbName = prop.get(dbNamesFile, dbShortName);

    int x = 50; int y = 150; int width = 150; int height = 220; //set Size and location 

    int [] indices = tblList.getSelectedIndices();

    panel = new PanelDraggable [indices.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length ; i++) {
        String tblName = tblList.getModel().getElementAt(i).toString();

        String sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE "+
                 "`TABLE_SCHEMA`='"+dbName+"' AND `TABLE_NAME`='"+tblName+"'";

        JList<?> columnslist = new JList<String>();
        columnslist.setModel(getListModel(dbName, sql, 1));
        JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(columnslist);
        panel[i] = new PanelDraggable(x, y , width, height, tblName, sc);

        MouseInputAdapter mousehandler = new TableMouseHandler();
        panel[i].addMouseListener(mousehandler);

        mainPanel.add(panel[i]);
        x+=15;
        y+=20;

    }
    revalidate(); 
    repaint();
}

 private class TableMouseHandler extends MouseInputAdapter {

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            removeComp = (JComponent) e.getComponent(); 
        }
 }

 public static void RemoveTable() {

     mainPanel.remove(removeComp);
 }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: It's difficult to think about how to do this because it shouldn't be done. A static function shouldn't alter an object directly. You could pass a mainPanel and removeComp argument into RemoveTable to get around this.

Comment: If I shouldn't do in this way, what are the other opportunities?

Comment: I'll make a formal post soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take in an instance of the TableManagement class as an argument for each panel, that way you don't have to do it in the static context. Also, I removed the unnecessary sub-classes for your mouseAdapters you were creating and created them in the more accepted way.

```
public class PanelDraggable extends JPanel {

    public PanelDraggable (..., final TableManagement tblManagement) {
        .
        .
        .
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void (MouseEvent e) {
                tblManagement.removeTable();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Then in your TableManagement Class

```
public void AddTables() {

    String dbShortName = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String dbName = prop.get(dbNamesFile, dbShortName);

    int x = 50; int y = 150; int width = 150; int height = 220; //set Size and location 

    int [] indices = tblList.getSelectedIndices();

    panel = new PanelDraggable [indices.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length ; i++) {
        String tblName = tblList.getModel().getElementAt(i).toString();

        String sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE "+
                 "`TABLE_SCHEMA`='"+dbName+"' AND `TABLE_NAME`='"+tblName+"'";

        JList<?> columnslist = new JList<String>();
        columnslist.setModel(getListModel(dbName, sql, 1));
        JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(columnslist);

        // There is an extra argument here. Whatever your 
        // mainPanel used to be in the static method
        panel[i] = new PanelDraggable(x, y , width, height, tblName, sc, mainPanel);
        panel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered() {
                removeComp = (JComponent) e.getComponent();   
            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(panel[i]);
        x+=15;
        y+=20;

    }
    revalidate(); 
    repaint();
}

 public void RemoveTable() {
     this.remove(removeComp);
 }
```

Side-Note: You should look into Java naming conventions. Only classes have their first character capitalized.